# Is that possible to expose the Kafka topics over the internet through HTTPS?

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are currently having a requirement of passing the data to topics from 3rd party API.  First, we have tried with HTTP bridge but looks like it is not supporting the HTTPS protocol. Now, we got some suggestions for having or creating the Kafka connector to solve this. Now, we got confused about whether Kafka connect can solve this or not. How it will be solved? I am looking for some suggestions for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect can send records to an HTTP(S) endpoint, or read from one and into Kafka. It will not allow external users to read through it, to get Kafka records.

The Strimzi Bridge or Confluent REST Proxy should both support HTTPS, even if that means you need to place either behind an SSL terminated reserve proxy such as Nginx, Caddy, etc.

Comment: Are you sure the Strimzi bridge supports HTTPS? If so, please provide more details on this. My understanding is from the strimzi doc, which supports the HTTP only. [link](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#con-securing-http-interface-bridge) @OneCricketeer

Comment: As answered - _even if that means SSL termination is handled by a reverse proxy_. Meaning, you expose HTTPS elsewhere, then an HTTP request is forwarded to the bridge, and returned via the proxy